# Check which user saw which page

Tags: statistics

How can I have analytics which show which registered user saw which page? Is there a plugin that can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Google Analytics, you can add [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) to the tracking code to pass a user ID.

Comment: Thanks, is there some plugin which makes this easier?